# Issue with returning substring. Second pair of eyes

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter

I think I really just need a second pair of eyes here. I am having some issues with returning the value of a substring. I have a tweet that I have split into an array of words and then I am using array filter to find the Twitter handle. When I do find the handle, I want to make sure that there is no ":" on the end of the tweet.

When I console log the value that I am trying to return, I get the Twitter handle with no colon on the end. The returned value seems to still have the colon. Take a look below. The Twitter handle has to make it through all the logic in order to be returned.

```
getTweetedBy: function(keywords) {
    // Assume keywords is equal to ['@AP:', 'this', 'is', 'a', 'tweet']
    return keywords.filter(function(el){
      if(el.substring(0, 1) === '@') {
        if(el.slice(-1) === ':') {
          // the value logged here is "@AP" as it should be
          console.log(el.substring(0, el.length - 1));
          return el.substring(0, el.length - 1);
        }
      }
    });
  }
```

When I run the code below, the console is logging ["@AP:"]. I need to remove the colon.

```
filterKeywords = commonFilters.filterKeywords(keywords);
tweetedBy = commonFilters.getTweetedBy(keywords);
storyLink = commonFilters.getTweetLink(keywords);
// The console is logging ["@AP:"]
console.log(tweetedBy);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

**EDIT:**
As noted below by David, filter is expecting a truthy or falsey statement to be returned. Can anyone think of a method that is better than filter? Only want to return one value. I know I can do this with a loop, but a method would be better.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to separate your filtering and mapping functions.  The first filter removes elements that don't match, and the second map transforms those matched values to whatever substring you want.

```
getTweetedBy: function(keywords) {
    // Assume keywords is equal to ['@AP:', 'this', 'is', 'a', 'tweet']
    return keywords
        .filter(function(el){
            return (el.substring(0, 1) === '@' && el.slice(-1) === ':');
        })
        .map(function(el){
            // the value logged here is "@AP" as it should be
            console.log(el.substring(0, el.length - 1));
            return el.substring(0, el.length - 1);
        });
}
```

Edit: Want it in one function?  Here you go:

```
getTweetedBy: function(keywords) {
    // Assume keywords is equal to ['@AP:', 'this', 'is', 'a', 'tweet']
    return keywords
        .reduce(function(matched, el){
            if (el.substring(0, 1) === '@' && el.slice(-1) === ':') {
                return matched.concat([ el.substring(0, el.length - 1) ]);
            }
            return matched;
        }, [])
}
```

Comment: Wow man! Very interesting. That is some great insight right there. Thank you! I would like to know, you can look into this if you want to, I am just curious, how this method would perform next to a for loop. Which one would run faster. Obviously, with such a small array length it wouldn't matter, but I would be interested to know. Thanks again!

Comment: Running two loops will be slower than a single forEach(fn) loop, which will be slower than a low-level for loop.  The reduce function probably performs poorly due to the `concat`-ing, but if this is for an array of a few elements, choose the one that is the most clear for future editing.

Answer (score 1):

`filter` expects a function that returns truthy/falsey value.

It doesn't collect the values returned by the supplied function, it collects the elements for which the function is truthy. There are a bunch of options, including collecting the matched elements with the additional processing your requirements dictate.

Comment: thanks for responding dave! What would be a better method?